# Excel: Increment Counter Button of Relative Cell

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I want to have a button to click that will increment the value of a cell.

However, rather than increment an absolutely referenced cell, I want to increment the value of a cell relative to the button location.

This is the type of code I am working with so far, however the key question of finding the event object location is proving difficult...

```
Sub increment_value()
this.Offset(0, -2).Value = this.Offset(0, -2).Value + 1
End Sub
```

This is what I want it to do (example only -> button in D5 increment B5 by 1. *Relative* is the key though!):

[image]

Sub thought: Is there an Excel equivalent to the Javascript keyword: `this`?

Comment: do you use `ActiveX` or standard form's button?

Comment: I'm using the VBA/macros in Excel

Comment: That is what I know. There are two types of button which you could place on the sheet. Which type do you use? if this is ActiveX then you will find the answer below.

Comment: Ah, I added a Form button, but now I see the ActiveX button. I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your button is an ActiveX one you could add the following code to it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -2) = _
            Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -2) + 1
End Sub
```

Where:

**`Me.`** refers to sheet where button is located.

**`.CommandButton1.`** refers to itself

**`.TopLeftCell`** is property which returns `Range object` of the cell where is located TopLeft corner of your button. So, be precise when you locate it in the sheet.

**Tried and tested!**