# Simple Macro in Excel to go to cell based on string value?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply a macro to a text box / button to go to a specific cell based on that cell's string value.
I am sorry this is such a newbie Q, but I can't find the syntax and appreciate anyone taking the time to help!
The macro cannot designate the cell number as rows will be added and deleted from this worksheet as it is used, and so the where the desired cell is located will change.
Essentially, trying to code a text box button with a macro to go to different areas of a worksheet with many, many rows without having to scroll so much!

Thank you!

Comment: you could think of solution close to one described in [THIS Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538465/excel-increment-counter-button-of-relative-cell/19538695#19538695)

Comment: record a macro a then modify the code

Answer (score 0):

Why bother when there is a built-in that is easy to use? Just type the row and column address to this box and press Enter to take you there.

Say initially you are at `A1` and want to go to `AA999`, typing in AA999 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will take you there right away.

[image: NameBox][image: AA999]

If you have named a Range, you can just type in that name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will take you there. Example: `FarAway` is named for range `AAA999:AAC1001`

[image: namedRange][image: FarAway Range]